# Automatically turning a profile to unpublished if membership is unpaid and v.v

Tags: users, rules

I am creating a website for a society, where members pay an annual fee. When members pay for the first time (through ubercart and 2checkout), they automatically receive a user role that enables them to create a member profile. I have set the membership to end a year after they have paid. I have also set up an e-mail reminder to be sent to the member, a week before, reminding them to renew their membership.

I've been playing with rules and relationships in views, unsuccessfully, to answer the following two questions, so I hope someone here has advice.

- How do I automatically render the member profile invisible to other members once the payment due date has passed?
- Is it possible to automatically render the same invisible profile visible should they renew their membership by paying and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I automatically render the member profile invisible to other members once the payment due date has passed?

By blocking the user you can stop access on expired user.

> Is it possible to automatically render the same invisible profile visible should they renew their membership by paying and if so, how?

For making it automatic so that a user can activate its account himself, you have to write a custom interface for that. (e.g. A block user tries to login, redirect to a page for user to enter his email address, then process his/her payment against his identity and unblock user)

```
$user = user_load('mail'=>$email);
user_save($user, array('status' => 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the Ubercart Recurring Payments and Subscriptions module; it sounds like you are homebrewing what they've already got working and a community of users battle-testing the logic: http://drupal.org/project/uc_recurring